# How to set the dtype of each column of a numpy array?

Tags: python, numpy

I want to create a 3 column numpy array (height, weight and gender). I have to define the column's names and the data type accordingly.
I will use this example of data :

```
1.8   70   1
1.6   65   0
```

I tried this :

```
Data = np.array([[1.80,70,1],[1.60,65,0]],
                dtype=[('Height (in m)', 'float'), 
                       ('Weight (in kg)', 'float'), 
                       ('Gender', 'int')])
```

However, when printing, I get this :

```
[[( 1.8,  1.8,  1) (70. , 70. , 70) ( 1. ,  1. ,  1)]
[( 1.6,  1.6,  1) (65. , 65. , 65) ( 0. ,  0. ,  0)]]
```

Instead of this :

```
[[ 1.8 70.   1. ]
[ 1.6 65.   0. ]]
```

Obtained with :

```
Data = np.array([[1.80,70,1],[1.60,65,0]])
```

What am I doing wrong ?
Thanks.

Comment: You need to read some more about compound dtypes and structured arrays.  You supply the data as a list of **tuples**.  The input should look like the output.  With 2 sets of values like this you want a **1d** array (shape (2,)) with 3 fields.

Comment: 3 column is not 3D. Please fix the title

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the correct way to create a structured array.  Note the display and shape.

```
In [230]: Data = np.array([(1.80,70,1),(1.60,65,0)],dtype=[('Height (in m)', 'float'), ('Weight
     ...:  (in kg)', 'float'), ('Gender', 'int')])
In [231]: Data
Out[231]: 
array([(1.8, 70., 1), (1.6, 65., 0)],
      dtype=[('Height (in m)', '<f8'), ('Weight (in kg)', '<f8'), ('Gender', '<i8')])
In [232]: Data.shape
Out[232]: (2,)
In [233]: Data['Weight (in kg)']
Out[233]: array([70., 65.])
```